# Toggles wont get updated Android?

Tags: android, toggle

In my app I'm creating toggles. And I've created them for Auto Rotation, Wifi, Bluetooth, Volume/Silent and Airplane. But the problem is when the user opens the app the toggle's wont get updated. For Example on app launch...

**System Toggles:**

```
Auto Rotation: ON
Wifi: ON
Bluetooth: ON
Volume/Silent: ON
Airplane: ON
```

**In my app:**

```
Auto Rotation: OFF
Wifi: OFF
Bluetooth: OFF
Volume/Silent: OFF
Airplane: OFF
```

So when the user opens the app either all sytem toggles should be OFF, or in my app toggles should be on. Got my problem? Any solution will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: means if system toggles are on so your app toggles should be off ? but when you come in your app, your app toggles also shows on ?

Comment: No no, I want one of them to get updated, like if one is on then other should be on, or if one is off other should be off, got it?

Comment: ok got it, now if you are able to handle on/off toggles for both like system and your app, than you can use "shared preference" concept to manage last status to each toggle and on that basis, you can set on/off system and app toggles vise-versa.

Comment: I've toggles in my app which are on then when user opens my app the system toggles should be updated to on, but they remain as they are...Got now?

Comment: first tell me, you are able to do code to handle on/off system toggles ?

Comment: so now just need to implement logic, like whenever you come setting screen, just get status of all system toggles and on that basis set reverse toggles of your app and same way if user update your app toggles, set reverse your system toggles(as you already said that you can handle system toggles), vice-verse, just use if else condition with this logic for each toggle.